# Is it possible to redirect a call?

Tags: ios, iphone

My client is providing an international / long distance call service at cheap price to people if they make such calls via his company (Yes. It's like an international phone card)

The following is what my client wants to make.

Let's assume I have bunch of international / long distance / local phone numbers to call stored on my iPhone. If I tap one of the local phone numbers, iOS just lets me directly call the number. Not a problem. However, **if it's an international or long distance number, iOS makes a call to the company instead** so that the user can use the service at cheaper price.

Of course, this should happen only in the application. I'm not trying to tweak how iOS works by default.

I wonder if it's technically possible on iOS.

---

### Update

I just came up with an idea that popping up a msg box if the tapped number is an international / long distance number before the following msg box by iPhone pops up.

[image]
Yup. before this one.

---

Can I show my custom msg box before the deafult one?

Comment: It is technically possible.  Whether or not it's against Apple policy and whether or not it would pass app review are questions that are off-topic for StackOverflow and should be directed to Apple instead.

Comment: thx for your suggestion, nhgrif. I took out the policy part.

Comment: That's an iOS6 alert.  It's worth mentioning that an app that doesn't support iOS7 won't pass Apple review under any circumstance.  You can include backwards compatibility, but you have to support iOS7.

Comment: I got the image from googling :) I will sure support iOS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds technically possible. The user can grant access to the contacts to the app which would allow the app to read names and phone numbers. The app could analyze the numbers and determine which ones are international and dial a LD service instead.

I would think that as long as the app is being completely clear to the user which service is being called and charges that may be incurred, I would think Apple would be okay with that.

The only other rule might be if the app looks too much like the built-in phone app or if it is determined the the functionality is redundant to the phone app. Good luck, Apple policy is sometimes a bit mysterious.

As for the alert, you can show any message, or even none at all.